# How can I sort List View Web Part in SharePoint Designer 2010?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, list-view-web-part

I'm trying to sort ListViewWebPart in Left hand navigation menu at Meeting Workspace Site, but Sort and Group button in submenu is disabled. How can I fix that?

[image: Sort and Group menu choice is disabled]